# How to convert WinProc message codes to text?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have defined a winproc message handler like so

```
WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

Is there a nice utility function to convert uMsg codes to text?  I need it for debugging. 
I can not seem to find it with google on msdn.   I could code it myself but it should exists already...

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/v-s/debug/article.php/c1267

Comment: A `switch` statement is a pretty good utility. Start looking in `winuser.h` for the definitions.

Comment: yeah the sample in the codeguru is pretty much what I would have written myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) if its mearly debugging you want, however, if you need it at a more code level, then you might need to use CPP defines to create the logging eg:

```
#define WNDMSG(x) case x: LogWndMessage(#x);
```